# When I .load a HTML template, JSON elements don't populate but they work fine as static HTML.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't think this is a broken code question as much as it is a question about understanding JS.

I have HTML templates that I load when an element is clicked. To be clear, there is already an HTML template loaded on `document.ready` that has all functionality working just fine. The HTML that loads is the exact HTML that is in place when you intitially load the page, aside from some small differences(images, etc...). This all loads no problem, but for some reason my JSON elements don't load. Is this because the actual javascript I wrote that is responsible for loading the JSON is within the document.ready wrap?

To be clear, the HTML is EXACTLY the same, aside from text and img src's. I have provided the JS though since that may be the issue.

Just looking for some guidance on why this may be occurring since I also have a few other JS/jquery strings of code that also don't work on template load(like hiding elements with .hide that work on document.ready no problem, but once the template loads, the elements aren't hiding).

This all sits in `$(document).ready`

```
var trinketJSON;
  $.getJSON("js/trinket.json", function (data) {
    trinketJSON = data;

    // TRINKET SELECTION TABLE
    $.each(trinketJSON, function (i, item) {
      $("<div>")
        .html(
          '<div class="trinket-tile"><div class="trinket-img" style=\'background-image: url("' +
          trinketJSON[i].RarityBG +
          '");\'><img src="' +
          trinketJSON[i].TrinketIMG +
          '" class="trinket-tile-img"></div><div class="trinket-effects"><ul><li class="trinket-effect">' +
          trinketJSON[i].EffectOne +
          '</li><li class="trinket-effect">' +
          trinketJSON[i].EffectTwo +
          '</li><li class="trinket-effect">' +
          trinketJSON[i].EffectThree +
          '</li><li class="trinket-effect">' +
          trinketJSON[i].EffectFour +
          '</li><li class="trinket-effect">' +
          trinketJSON[i].EffectFive +
          '</li><li class="trinket-effect">' +
          trinketJSON[i].EffectSix +
          '</li></ul></div><div class="trinket-info"><ul><li class="trinket-name">' +
          trinketJSON[i].TrinketName +
          '</li><li class="trinket-rarity">' +
          trinketJSON[i].Rarity +
          '</li><li class="trinket-class">' +
          trinketJSON[i].Class +
          '</li><li class="trinket-set"></ul></div></div>'
        )
        .appendTo(".trinket-select");
    });
```

Comment: Not certain what issue is? The HTML is not appended to `document`?

Comment: just an FYI for future reference, inside `$.each(trinketJSON, function (i, item) {` function, `trinketJSON[i]` is `item` - save you some typing :p

Comment: Can we assume that an element with class `trinket-select` exists at the time?

Comment: @guest271314, the issue is that when I load an HTML template, the above JSON isn't appending to .trinket-select but it works on the same HTML with zero issues when it is just part of the native HTML of index.html.

Comment: Are any errors logged at `console`?  Is `data` an object or an array? Can you create a plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: Yeah, give me some time to re-create it as a code snippet. There is a lot of code. Will update shortly. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @dbrree We do not need the entire code base. Only brief `JSON` reflective of the full `JSON`, HTML and any event handlers or code that dynamically appends elements to `document`

Comment: @guest271314, there are no errors. Also going to add the HTML that shows where the JSON elements should be loading.

Comment: Generating HTML by string concatenation is going to cause many issues, is difficult to work with, difficult to extend, and a nightmare to debug. 

I suggest using existing APIs (`document.createElement`, etc) to create the elements, it will be much easier to use, modify etc.

Comment: As @JaromandaX mentioned, why do you use `trinketJSON[i]` instead of `item`?

Comment: totally agree with DirkyJerky.  angular, react, knockout, vue, or any of the other million frameworks out there is your friend.

Comment: I have a feeling it's the wrap in `document.ready` that causes this issue. If you dynamically load html into your page with jquery, I don't believe `document.ready` fires again, in which case any code inside it is not executed. You may have to execute this code some other way on dynamic reload.

Comment: @BryanDellinger How is a "framework" related to Question?

Comment: `This all sits in $(document).ready` - so it gets run exactly once, on document ready - how do you expect that code to run again? It's not clear from the snippet you posted

Comment: @JaromandaX, that's what I was thinking and I'm glad most of you think the same. So my question would be simple, how can I re-fire those functions? Since when I am loading a new HTML template it is loading after the document.ready. How would I re-fire those functions? That's 100% of the problem and now I know the issue, I just don't know how to remedy it. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: Also to @DirkyJerky & Bryan Dellinger, I plan to re-write everything in vue.js actually, but I'm so close to being done with this as is I want to launch it and re-code it after. But... it may appear I should just re-do it now if I am going to run into issues like this.

Comment: `how can I re-fire those functions` by doing so on a click event - we can't tell you exactly what to do, because you haven't shown any code for handling clicks

Comment: @JaromandaX, I think you just answered it for me.

Comment: @JaromandaX, so I put the JS that I provided above in an .on('click') event, and it worked perfectly. I know I didn't provide much code and I'm sorry for that as I know it's not best Stackoverflow posting practice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: well, you probably learned more by not having the answer written for you anyway :p

Comment: @JaromandaX, if you would like, feel free to post the comment you left about the click event as the answer and I'll confirm it.